# How should I go about changing the state of siblings when a child is clicked in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I just ran into the problem where I need to select a single component in an array, but when I select that one child component, I want it to change the state/styling of the sibling components.

So let's say I have 3 child components in an array. How can I select one item and style it to look like it's selected, but then deselect/destyle all other siblings?

I have an example project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-river-h20cx?file=/src/Parent.js
I want to only have one child item green at a time, when selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion it's more efficient to control the `selected` props from the parent and also passing `onClick` into the child component and utilize the child component as presentational component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedId: 1,
      childArray: [
        {
          id: 1,
          Name: "Child 1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          Name: "Child 2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          Name: "Child 3"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleClickChild = this.handleClickChild.bind(this);
  }

  handleClickChild(id) {
    this.setState({ selectedId: id });
  }

  render() {
    var childObjects = this.state.childArray.map(item => (
      <Child
        text={item.Name}
        selected={item.id === this.state.selectedId}
        onClick={() => this.handleClickChild(item.id)}
      />
    ));

    return <div className="parent">{childObjects}</div>;
  }
}
```

you can see this codesandbox that I've made based on yours https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-haze-vy75f?file=/src/Parent.js

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware that you could send a conditional bool statement as a prop. i.e. 'item.id === this.state.selectedId' thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html): move state to the parent component and let it control it while child components are stateless.